# Extra blank lines in tabularx

Tags: spacing, tabularx

I have written a macro that uses the functions in `xstring`:

```
\newcommand{\yyyymmmdd}[1]
{\IfSubStr{#1}{-01-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-01-}{-Jan-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-02-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-02-}{-Feb-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-03-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-03-}{-Mar-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-04-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-04-}{-Apr-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-05-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-05-}{-May-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-06-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-06-}{-Jun-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-07-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-07-}{-Jul-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-08-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-08-}{-Aug-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-09-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-09-}{-Sep-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-10-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-10-}{-Oct-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-11-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-11-}{-Nov-}}{}
\IfSubStr{#1}{-12-}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-12-}{-Dec-}}{} }
```

What this does is change a date from 2015-10-07 to 2015-Oct-07.  It works great, sort of.  Now when I print it in a `tabularx`:

```
\begin{tabularx}{19cm}{p{1.75cm}C{1.85cm}C{2cm}L{2.5cm}L{4cm}L{4cm}} \hline
  \textbf{Invoice \#} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Customer \#} & \textbf{P.O. \#}
   & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Salesperson} \\ [0.5em]
  <%invnumber%> & \yyyymmmdd{<%invdate%>} & <%customernumber%> & <%ponumber%> 
  & <%shippingpoint%> & <%employee%> \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

I get a blank line before and after the line of data.   If I take out `\yyyymmmdd` and just print `<%invdate%>` I do not get the blank lines.  What would cause this?

Comment: You're probably using something else to insert the "correct date" instead of `<%invdate%>`, as (La)TeX considers `%` to represent a comment character. My guess is you have spurious spaces in your macro, causing the problem. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj).

Comment: Please tell us how the `L` and `C` column types a defined. (Are they just raggedright and centered versions of `X` If so, why do they have explicit widths?) Please also provide at least two valid non-header rows of input for the `tabularx` environment, so that we can test what's going on.

Comment: there is no possible way `tabularx` can do anything useful with this table, all the column widths are specified in advance, and the cells are (I would guess) small items not involving linebreaking. `tabularx` is all about adjusting the widths for linebreaking with a column.

Answer (score 1):

With a simpler solution for the date macro. However, I do not know how you get the data. The reason why I used only text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{p{#1}}% dummy
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{p{#1}}% dummy

\newcommand\yyyymmmdd[1]{\YYYYMMDD#1}
\def\YYYYMMDD#1-#2-#3{#1-%
    \ifcase#2
      \or Jan\or Feb\or Mar\or Apr\or May\or Jun\or Jul%
      \or Aug\or Sep\or Oct\or Nov\or Dec\fi
   -#3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{19cm}{p{1.75cm}C{1.85cm}C{2cm}L{2.5cm}L{4cm}L{4cm}} \hline
        \textbf{Invoice \#} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Customer \#} & \textbf{P.O. \#}
        & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Salesperson} \\ [0.5em]
        foo & \yyyymmmdd{2015-07-07} & foo & bar 
        & foobar & foobaz \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```